# Bundle a param passed function including all external data

Tags: javascript, parsing, bundling-and-minification

I want to create a function `bundleFunction()` that gets as a parameter a function and bundles it into a string, including all the external dependencies that it uses.

Example usage:

```
const f1 = 1;
const f2 = 2;

function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

bundleFunction(() => {
    const result = add(f1, f2);
    return result;
});
```

And the return value of `bundleFunction()` to look something like this:

```
"function () { const result = ((a, b) => { return a + b })(1, 2); return result; }
```

Is it even possible to do something like this or something similar? Thanks in advance!

I was thinking to try to use `eval()` but wasn't able to come with any viable solution.

Comment: Where would the arrow function come from? Do you want to replace common functions with arrow functions?

Comment: It doesn't matter, it can be a normal function or arrow function. I just tried to replicate how it'd look if there was a bundler that converted the function.

Comment: In short that's what I want to do: bundle & minify a function but with the external values used by it.

Comment: I think you need a JavaScript engine that reads and interprets the source code as text. You could also try to serialize the functions and replace them. Why do you want to inline the functions? That's not what a bundler or minifier would do. You could check how TypeScript or Babel work. They're open source and do similar things. I'd say the inlining is complex. The values could be dynamic at runtime. That's usually not possible.